# How to center the icon in the button

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my ionic 3 project, the button icon doesn't become centered. When I test in browser it works correctly and in android devices it also shows correctly in the center.

But only in ios devices does it not show in the center.

[image]

The screenshot above is from an ios device. In that the +,- symbols are not aligned in the center.

Html code:

```
<ion-col style="display: contents">
  <button primary large class="inbtn" (click)="decrement()">
      <ion-icon name="remove" ></ion-icon>
</button>
<h2 style="margin-left: 7px;margin-top: 0px;font-size: 2.4rem;"><b>{{currentNumber}}</b></h2>
<button primary large class="inbtn" (click)="increment()" >
  <ion-icon name="add" ></ion-icon>
</button>
</ion-col>
```

css:

```
.inbtn{
     height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 7px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:  #d8d8d8 !important;
    text-align: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 27):

Here is css what are you looking for you can fix height and width according to your requirement;

```
.inbtn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer :) Thanks

Comment: @ShellZero Thank you

Answer (score 3):

html code

```
 <ion-item>
   <ion-button class="center" color="success">Next</ion-button>
 </ion-item>
```

CSS

```
.center{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use an exact pixel amount for the margin-left, because it can vary with the device used(desktop,android or ios),There for it is better to use a percentage value as the margin-left and margin-right.

```
.inbtn{
         height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: large;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-right:25%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color:  #d8d8d8 !important;
        text-align: center;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
        }
```

If 25% is not enough for the margin ,pls feel free to increase and change the margin percentage according to your need.
And if this didn't work pls comment below :)